# Работа с заменой контекста в javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет. Народ, подскажите пожалуйста по поводу одной проблемы в сфере фронтенда (html, css, js). В общем у меня есть задача написать прогу, которая будет рисовать круги в канвасе по нажатию на кнопку мышки, причём у этих кругов будет цвет и размер, которые устанавливает пользователь. Я написал класс и дал ему два свойства color и size, а также метод drawLine, который отвечает за рисование кругов. код всего этого предоставляю ниже.

```js
class Line {

    constructor(color, size){
        this.color = color;
        this.size = size;
        
    }
    
    drawLine(){
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
            ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
            ctx.arc(e.clientX, e.clientY, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2);
            ctx.fill();
            console.log(this.color);
        })
    }
}

new Line(generalColor.value).drawLine();
```

Проблема в том, что метод рисует круги, но всегда чёрные. В принципе понятно почему, ведь в строке `ctx.fillStyle = this.color;` `this` ссылает нас к элементу, на котором произошло событие, т.е к канвасу. Вопрос такой: как вернуть к this в методе drawLine контекст класса, т.е чтобы this ссылалось на класс, а не на канвас? Я пробовал менять контекст с помощью метода `call` вот так:
`new Line(generalColor.value).drawLine.call(Line);`
но не получилось. Пробовал как-то это обойти костылями, тоже не получилось. В общем опытные JSеры помогите пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо за помощь.
P.s. Хочу решить эту задачку объектно-ориентированным программированием.

Comment: Если вам мой ответ помог, отметьте его галочкой (возле счётчика голосов)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что `function` имеет свой **this**. Можно использовать, например, стрелочную функцию, у которой нету своего **this**

```js
class Line {
    constructor(color, size){
        this.color = color;
        this.size = size;
        
    }
    
    drawLine(){
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
            ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
            ctx.arc(e.clientX, e.clientY, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2);
            ctx.fill();
        });
    }
}
```

Вот как можно сделать, чтобы работало:

```js
class Line {
  constructor(options) {
    this.canvas = options.canvas;
    this.color = options.color;
    this.size = options.size;
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.addListener();
  }

  addListener() {
    this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
      this.ctx.beginPath();
      this.ctx.arc(e.x, e.y, this.size, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      this.ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
      this.ctx.fill();
      this.ctx.closePath();
    });
  }
}

const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.body.prepend(canvas);

const line = new Line({
  canvas: canvas,
  color: 'red',
  size: '10'
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот, должно сработать:

```js
class Line {
    constructor(color, size){
        this.color = color;
        this.size = size;
        
    }
    
    drawLine(){
        let line = this; // Трюк, которым все пользуются
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
            ctx.fillStyle = line.color;
            ctx.arc(e.clientX, e.clientY, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2);
            ctx.fill();
            console.log(line.color);
        })
    }
}
```

Хотя, вы точно уверены что алгоритм верен? Выглядит странно...